# Can't reinstall MongoDB on Ubuntu 17

Tags: server, 17.04, mongodb, npm

I uninstalled before MongoDB but now I can't install it due to this error:

```
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe).
```

I ran this command -> `sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org`

My terminal output is following:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
libboost-chrono1.62.0 libboost-program-options1.62.0 libgoogle-perftools4
libtcmalloc-minimal4 libunwind8 libyaml-cpp0.5v5 linux-headers-4.13.0-16
linux-headers-4.13.0-16-generic linux-headers-4.13.0-21
linux-headers-4.13.0-21-generic linux-image-4.13.0-16-generic
linux-image-4.13.0-21-generic linux-image-extra-4.13.0-16-generic
linux-image-extra-4.13.0-21-generic linux-signed-image-4.13.0-16-generic
linux-signed-image-4.13.0-21-generic mongo-tools
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server mongodb-org-shell mongodb-org-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed:
mongodb-org mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server mongodb-org-shell
mongodb-org-tools
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/66.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 276 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package mongodb-org-shell.
(Reading database ... 316734 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-shell_3.6.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-shell (3.6.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mongodb-org-server.
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-server_3.6.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-server (3.6.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mongodb-org-mongos.
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-mongos_3.6.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-mongos (3.6.2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-tools_3.6.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-tools (3.6.2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-tools_3.6.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/bsondump', which is also in package mongo-tools 3.2.11-1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Selecting previously unselected package mongodb-org.
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org_3.6.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org (3.6.2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-tools_3.6.2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

After running `apt --fix-broken install`,  the output is as follows:

```
apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libboost-chrono1.62.0 libboost-program-options1.62.0 libgoogle-perftools4 libtcmalloc-minimal4 libunwind8 libyaml-cpp0.5v5 linux-headers-4.13.0-16
  linux-headers-4.13.0-16-generic linux-headers-4.13.0-21 linux-headers-4.13.0-21-generic linux-image-4.13.0-16-generic
  linux-image-4.13.0-21-generic linux-image-extra-4.13.0-16-generic linux-image-extra-4.13.0-21-generic linux-signed-image-4.13.0-16-generic
  linux-signed-image-4.13.0-21-generic mongo-tools
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  mongodb-org-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mongodb-org-tools
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/34.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 150 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 316761 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-tools_3.6.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-tools (3.6.2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-tools_3.6.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/bsondump', which is also in package mongo-tools 3.2.11-1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-tools_3.6.2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can force installation of package:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-all /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-tools_3.6.2_amd64.deb
```

Then resume with:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: thanks N0rbert, it worked. I executed your command and simply added one file in /lib/systemd/system/mongod.service.  after restart it started mongodb

Comment: now I have successfully  installed mongodb-org, but when I started it then problem occurs again. mongodb shell is working fine but when i entered the command as **sudo systemctl enable mongod** , it gives output as
`Failed to enable unit: Unit file mongod.service does not exist. `@N0rbert

Comment: I do not know how to fix this. Try to read official documentation or switch to version from official repository.

Comment: It solved my problem thank you so much.